# jQuery and XHTML layout problems in ie7

Tags: jquery, xhtml, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, height

I am back again with more layout problems on my up and coming website. I am able to achieve the proper animation, positioning and results with my layout / splash on every modern browser (excluding ie7 or older).

I have an image in the center of the page, that is text-align: center'd, and pushed to a vertical center by having a div (#SPLASH_HEAD) set to 50% on the top half of the page. The loading animation changes the height of #SPLASH_HEAD to 0px, to  drag the image to the top (and then do other things).

In ie7 (or compatability mode), it appears that there is an error in jquery-1.4.2.min.js, line 116 char 165 (which I dont think has anything to do with the actual jQuery file itself). The splash is not centered either vertically (#SPLASH_HEAD does not register at 50% of window height) and is not centered properly with margin-left. Also, none of the other elements are hidden properly (with .hide()) as ie7 does not appear to be loading all of my jQuery / javascript.

heres a link: [www.voidsync.com/test](http://www.voidsync.com/test/) (it would be easier to view the source on there)

thanks!

Comment: did you mean "excluding ie6 or older"?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using .livequery instead of jQuery .live? I'm not sure if this is related though, but I had problems with using livequery w/ 1.4+ (don't know if it IE related) so I switched back to 1.3.2 instead.

Comment: @keithjgrant - this does not work in ie7 or older.

@nolabel - I am using livequery as it seems to have more capabilities than .live (like hijaxing anchor links, or running functions on AJAX loaded content) as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 66 of your jquery.js you're passing the value "inherit." IE sometimes has a fit with this value.

```
$("#CONTAINER").css("height","inherit");
```

Try commenting out that line. Then, refresh your page in IE7. If the problem persists, change the value to either "auto" or "".

If that doesn't solve the problem, try moving your design back to jquery 1.3.2. I found a bug in jquery just yesterday, and it's possible you have too. GOOD LUCK!

Comment: I needed to pass a value to bring all of the elements back to their original starting positions if the user was to click "back" after having loaded the splash.

I created an exception, to set the height to "100%" in IE7 or older, and "inherit" in all other browsers, and everything is working now. Thanks!